# Rails getting a user name of a comment using join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User Model:

```
id, name, email
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

A Micropost Model:

```
id, content, title
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

and a Comment Model:

```
id, content, user_id, micropost_id
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
  has_one :micropost
  has_one :user
```

I would like to access the User Name of each comment through a comment itself.  For example, I can get the user's name through micropost with `micropost.user.name` which will give me the User name of the user associated with a particular micropost.  In the same vain, I'd like something like comment.user.name or in sql terms

```
select user.name from User as user join Comment as comment where user.id = comment.user_id and comment.id = 12;
```

When I try to run `comment.user.name` I get an error:

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."comment_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [[nil, 3]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.comment_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."comment_id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

I see the problem with the SQL is there is no users.comment_id, but I would like for the SQL to actually be users.id.  How can I write this?

Comment: You probably are mixing the meanings of belongs_to and has_many. Read [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Is+it+a+belongs_to+or+has_one+association-3F)

Comment: get rid of the has_one associations. you don't have a belongs_to and has_one for the same association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `has_one` declarations from your comment model.  In this relationship, a comment will only ever have one user and one micropost, as denoted by `belongs_to`.  Add has_one is confusing it.

Simplifying it should remove your error.

```
# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code what i understand your comment model would be.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :content, :user_id, :micropost_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
end
```

Then in your comments controller, which you access through the micropost_comments_path(@micropost) URL helper you can do the following to build the association in the create action:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.micropost = @micropost
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
    ...
end
```